# Jquery ajax() not working with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing problem while making ajax call in bootstrap modal.
Below is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#pBtn").click(function() {
                 $.ajax({
                    url : "getAll",
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }}); 
            });
        });



 <div class="modal fade" id="pModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" id="pBtn">View</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But request doesn't reach the server.
I see the below error in browsers console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: f[b] is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.b [as modal] (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Object.success (login.action:37)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a quick look at your error message and it seems to be a problem with the actual modal itself. Take a look at https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox/issues/213 to solve that issue.

Now for your Ajax request, try changing it to the below:

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('.modal-body').load('/path/to/getAll'); return false" >View</a>
```

It's a more up to date way of doing it and is normally a lot easier to troubleshoot when it does fail.

And just to explain the code:

$('.modal-body') is where the content will be placed, I would recommend putting a div inside the modal-body with an ID and using that as an identifier instead.

.load('/path/to/getAll') is the call to your, i'm assuming PHP script.

return false simple keeps you in the same place on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget to add before the firing the request

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="pBtn">View</a>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/*  $("#pBtn").click(function() {
         */
    });
$("#pBtn").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked."); 
    $.ajax({
            url : "localhost/getAll", // write here absolute url .. including action name . if you have routed then no issue. ie. you can also put relative path but make sure getAll have valid action name . 
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }}); 
    });
</script>
```